# file "is damaged and can't be opened" when opening twice a mounted file

Tags: macos, file, osx-gatekeeper

I have a mounted directory to access some images. 
When opening an image for the first time with `open /mounted_dir/foo.jpg` it opens the image in preview. 
When repeating the same command it gives the error: 
`/mounted_dir/foo.jpg is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Trash.`

I have seen this error message on the web but only for apps, not image files. Furthermore, the file in question doesn't appear damaged, eg:

```
cp /mounted_dir/foo.jpg /tmp/foo.jpg
diff /mounted_dir/foo.jpg /tmp/foo.jpg #no difference
open /tmp/foo.jpg #works
open /mounted_dir/foo.jpg #same error
```

Is there any other way than setting preference to do this (in System Preferences > Security & Privacy:  Set "Allow Applications Downloaded From" to 'Anywhere') ?

Ideally, I'd like either a open --force mode or a command line way to tell the system that the file isn't damaged, or (last resort) command line to set the System Preferences > Security & Privacy option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the com.apple.quarantine flag is set, and if so, remove it.

```
➜  xattr foo.pdf
com.apple.quarantine
➜  xattr -d com.apple.quarantine foo.pdf
➜  xattr foo.pdf
```

Alternatively, disable Gatekeeper. See here:
https://boxcryptor.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/688364-why-am-i-receiving-the-error-%22filexyz-is-damaged-and-can-t-be-opened-you-should-move-it-to-the-trash-%22-under-mountain-lion-

Comment: Thanks! so it is indeed an apple bug.